# The converse of statement $\|u\|_1\leq \epsilon\|u\|_2+C_\epsilon\|u\|_3$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here $\|\cdot\|_1$, $\|\cdot\|_2$, and $\|\cdot\|_3$ are 3 different norms on space $E$. I am trying to show an inequality such that for each $\epsilon>0$ I have $C_\epsilon$ such that 
$$  \|u\|_1\leq \epsilon\|u\|_2+C_\epsilon\|u\|_3 \tag 1$$
for all $u\in E$, where as $\epsilon\to 0$ we have $C_\epsilon\to\infty$

To prove this I need to use contradiction. Hence by assuming $(1)$ does not hold I should obtain an sequence $(u_n)$ such that 
$$  \|u_n\|_1\geq 1+n\|u_n\|_3  \tag 2$$

It looks clear to me before but now I got confused how I obtain $(2)$... So, by assuming the contradiction, I have there exists a $\epsilon_0>0$ such that there are no such $C_\epsilon$ can do the job. That is, I can take $u_n$, for each $n$, such that 
$$  \|u_n\|_1\geq \epsilon_0\|u_n\|_{2}+n\|u_n\|_3  $$
Hence, by taking 
$$ v_n:=\frac{u_n}{\epsilon_0\|u_n\|_2} $$
I have
$$  \|v_n\|_1\geq 1+n\|v_n\|_3  $$
but somehow feel un-comfortable with my argument... Can anybody have a look and tell me is there something wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I think you mean "negation" (not A), rather than "converse" (if B then A). Also, to prove (1) you need to know *something* about the norms involved. It's not true in complete generality.

Comment: Yea of course. The question give more information like norm 2 is compact embedded in 3 and 3 is continuous embedded in 1. (or another way I don't remember...) But I got confused on negation part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part "$C_\epsilon\to\infty$" does not add anything; we can always make $C_\epsilon$ bigger. So, the statement to be proved is 
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists C \ \forall u\quad  \|u\|_1\leq \epsilon\|u\|_2+C\|u\|_3  $$
Its negation is
$$\exists \epsilon>0 \ \forall C \ \exists u\quad  \|u\|_1> \epsilon\|u\|_2+C\|u\|_3  $$
which is conveniently used by letting $C  = n$ and thus obtaining a sequence $u_n$ with 
$$ \|u_n\|_1> \epsilon\|u_n\|_2+n\|u_n\|_3  $$
And this point one can use homogeneity to make one of three norms of $u_n$ equal to $1$. (Which is what you did, with the second norm). The rest depends on what is known about those norms.

Comment: Dear @Fundamental: I just passed my Oral exam! Although I don't know who you are or where you live, but I really really thankful for your help over last several months. Thank you!!